# Py_Finalize() crashes after error in Python

Tags: python, c

I'm trying to call some python code using `Py_CompileString()` and `PyEval_EvalCode()`. It works fine, but when the Python Code contains an error `Py_Finalize()` craches.

```
Py_Initialize();

PyObject* code = Py_CompileString("pprint('Hello World')", "", Py_file_input);
PyObject* m = PyImport_AddModule("__main__");
PyObject* d = PyModule_GetDict(m);
Py_DECREF(m);
PyObject* r = PyEval_EvalCode(code, d, d);
Py_DECREF(d);
if (!r)
    PyErr_Print();
Py_DECREF(code);

Py_Finalize();
```

The Output is as expected:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'pprint' is no defined
```

But then at the call to `Py_Finalize()` the program crashes.If I change line 3 to

```
PyObject* code = Py_CompileString("print('Hello World')", "", Py_file_input);
```

the program runs and terminates fine. Whats going wrong here?

If i run the program in gdb i get this output:

```
Windows:
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x1e01a030 in python32!PyType_IsSubtype () from C:\Windows\SysWOW64\python32.dll

Linux:
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xb7ef17bb in visit_decref (op=0xb78c87ec, data=0x0) at Modules/gcmodule.c:321
321     Modules/gcmodule.c: File or Directory not found.
        in Modules/gcmodule.c
```

Comment: Why aren't you checking the result of each step?

Comment: I didn't check because I thought m & d wouldn't change because they have no connection to the code. And this is true: None of them returns an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The actual reason why this fails is not that you're calling `Py_DECREF` too early. It's that you're calling at at all!

PyImport_AddModule returns a *borrowed* reference. Which means you're not allowed to call `Py_DECREF` at all unless you have actually taken control over it (for example by increasing the reference count via `Py_INCREF`).

Python will automatically garbage collect the module reference on `Py_Finalize`. No additional action necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!r) {
    PyErr_Print();
    PyErr_Clear(); 
}
```

Will clear the error and allow you to call `Py_Finalize()` successfully.

Comment: What happens if you add `PyErr_Print(0);` on the line after `PyErr_Print();`? If that doesn't work, please edit your post to provide the actual crash information.

Comment: `Too many arguments to funciton 'void PyErr_Print()'`. I'm running Windows how do i obtain actual crash information? The program just closes with a dialog box "test.exe is not working anymore".

Comment: That's a big question. How are you compiling? If it's with gcc, try Googling "gdb windows", if it's Visual Studio or similar, Google "debugging with Visual Studio" or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have found the error myself now. You can only call `Py_DECREF(m)` after evalizing the code and checking it for errors. So the working program is this:

```
Py_Initialize();

PyObject* code = Py_CompileString("pprint('Hello World')", "", Py_file_input);
PyObject* m = PyImport_AddModule("__main__");
PyObject* d = PyModule_GetDict(m);
PyObject* r = PyEval_EvalCode(code, d, d);
Py_DECREF(d);
if (!r)
    PyErr_Print();
Py_DECREF(m);
Py_DECREF(code);

Py_Finalize();
```